# Reduce JSON object containing JSON objects into an array of the form [Path, Value]

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

I'm trying to reduce a JSON object of nested objects, arrays, and strings into a single array of the paths and values.

Expected input:

```js
appleObjects = {
  'apples': {
    'colors': ['red', 'green', 'yellow'],
    'owner': 'Person1',
    'types': [
      {name: 'fuji', flavor: 'good'}
    ]
  },
  'pears': {
    'colors': ['red', 'green', 'yellow'],
    'owner': 'Person1',
    'types': [
      {name: 'small', flavor: 'surprising'},
      {name: 'large', flavor: 'bold'}
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```js
appleValues = [
  {path: 'apples.colors', value: 'red'},
  {path: 'apples.colors', value: 'green'},
  {path: 'apples.colors', value: 'yellow'},
  {path: 'apples.owner', value: 'Person1'},
  {path: 'apples.types', value: {name: 'fuji', flavor: 'sweet?'}}
  ...
]
```

So far, I'm working towards using nested reduce functions and/or recursion but as it's in a web app I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way or even a library out there that already does something similar.

Here's what I'm working with so far. Currently react is complaining of too much recursion so clearly this is not the best way to go about accomplishing this:

```js
  myReducer = (p, obj) => {

    Object.entries(obj ?? []).reduce((acc, currVal, currIdx) => {
      if(typeof currVal === undefined) {
        return acc
      }
      if(typeof currVal === "string") {
        return {
          basePath: acc.basePath,
          outputArr:  acc.outputArr.push({
            path: acc.basePath + '.' + currVal[0],
            value: currVal[1]
          })
        }
      }
      if(typeof currVal === "object") {
        return {
          basePath: acc.basePath,
          outputArr:  acc.outputArr.concat(this.myReducer(acc.basePath + '.' + currVal[0], currVal[1]))
        }
      }
      return acc
    }, {basePath: p, outputArr: []})
  }



  getArrayOfApplesValues = () => {
    const {
      applesObjects
    } = this.state

    if (applesObjects === null) return []

    Object.entries(applesObjects).reduce((acc, currVal, currIdx) => {
      if(typeof currVal[1] === "object") {
        return {
          path: acc.basePath,
          outputArr: acc.outputArr.concat(this.myReducer (acc.basePath + '.' + currVal[0], currVal[1]))
        }
      }
      return acc
    }, {basePath: '', outputArr: []})
  }
```

Forgive my lack of apple knowledge in the examples.

Comment: Your data format is not valid..`'types': {      {name: 'fuji', flavor: 'good'}    }` - object with no key? ant this: `{      {name: 'small', flavor: 'surprising'},      {name: 'large', flavor: 'bold'}    }` - should it be an array?

Comment: Yeah, types should be an array.

Comment: Is it required to use reduce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive approach, Use `reduce` and `Object.etnries`

```js
const appleObjects = {
  apples: {
    colors: ["red", "green", "yellow"],
    owner: "Person1",
    types: [{ name: "fuji", flavor: "good" }]
  },
  pears: {
    colors: ["red", "green", "yellow"],
    owner: "Person1",
    types: [
      { name: "small", flavor: "surprising" },
      { name: "large", flavor: "bold" }
    ]
  }
};

const getKeysArr = (obj, prefix) => {
  var arr = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    const temp_key = prefix ? `${prefix}.${key}` : key;
    if (typeof value === "string" || typeof value === "number") {
      acc.push({ path: temp_key, value: value });
    } else if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      value.forEach(item => acc.push({ path: temp_key, value: item }));
    } else {
      acc.push(getKeysArr(value, key));
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
  return arr;
};

console.log(getKeysArr(appleObjects, ""));
```

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of this to account for null and undefined values.

Comment: @K-Log, oh ok, missed it. Thats great. Can you also edit above answer so that future reader might benefit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `reduce` you have to run your code recursively and try to flatten your object into an array using below function:

```js
let appleObjects = {
  'apples': {
    'colors': ['red', 'green', 'yellow'],
    'owner': 'Person1',
    'types': [
      {name: 'fuji', flavor: 'good'}
    ]
  },
  'pears': {
    'colors': ['red', 'green', 'yellow'],
    'owner': 'Person1',
    'types': [
      {name: 'small', flavor: 'surprising'},
      {name: 'large', flavor: 'bold'}
    ]
  }
};

let flatten = (obj, prefix, result) => {
    result = result || [];
    for(let key of Object.keys(obj)){
        let keyExpr = prefix  ? `${prefix}.${key}` : `${key}`;
        if(Array.isArray(obj[key])){
           obj[key].forEach(x => result.push({path: keyExpr, value: x}));
        }
        else if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
            flatten(obj[key], keyExpr, result);
        }        
        else {
            result.push({path: keyExpr, value: obj[key]})
        }
    }
    return result;
}

let result = flatten(appleObjects);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

@mickl's answer is great but you might as well try this.

```
let fruits = {
  apples: {
    "colors": ["red", "green", "yellow"],
    "owner": "Person1",
    "types": [
      {name: "fuji", flavor: "good"}
    ]
  },
  pears: {
    "colors": ["red", "green", "yellow"],
    "owner": "Person1",
    "types": [
      {name: "small", flavor: "surprising"},
      {name: "large", flavor: "bold"}
    ]
  }
}
```

```
let arr = []
let fruitsArr = Object.entries(fruits)

fruitsArr.forEach(fruit => {
  let properties = fruit[1]
  let keys = Object.entries(fruit[1]).map(x => x[0])

  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (!Array.isArray(properties[key])) {
      return arr.push({
        path: `${fruit[0]}.${key}`,
        value: properties[key]
      })
    }

    if (typeof properties[key][0] === 'string') {
      properties[key].forEach(x => {
        return arr.push({
          path: `${fruit[0]}.${key}`,
          value: x
        })
      })
    }

    if (typeof properties[key][0] === 'object') {
      return arr.push({
        path: `${fruit[0]}.${key}`,
        value: properties[key][0]
      })
    }
  })
})
```